# New-Smbshare throws error when working with UNC path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script where I can create home folders for users on a primary domain controller or on all domain controllers for later DFS configuration. Script works like a charm when I write directly to A:$homeFolder. But in order to write to backup domain controllers I have to use the format \DC01.carpal.local\A$\homeFolder, and it throws an error that the syntax isn't correct. Creating the folder works, sharing doesn't. Error and code below [image]

```
function Set-HomeFolder
{
    $fqdn = Get-ADDomain | Select -ExpandProperty ReplicaDirectoryServers
    $fqdn[0]

    function Set-HomePDC
    {
        Get-HomeShareInfo

        $PBCPath =  '\\'+$fqdn[0]+'\'+$global:FolderVol+'\'                     ## \\dc01.carpal.local\A$\homeFolder\ ##
        New-Item -Path $PBCPath -Name $global:homeFolder -ItemType "directory"

        $company = Read-Host "Create home folders for users from company"       ## Root OU where users reside ##
        Write-Host $PBCPath$global:homeFolder

        New-SmbShare -Name $global:shareName -Path $PBCPath$global:homeFolder -FullAccess ("Administrator") -ChangeAccess ("DL_$company")
        
        $userRoot = '\\'+$fqdn[0]+'\'+$global:homeFolder+'\'                                           
        $homeDrive = Read-Host "Enter the name of the drive letter"                          
        $homeDrive = $homeDrive + ":"  
        

        $samName = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=$company,$global:ou" | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName


        foreach ($name in $samName)
        {   
            $homeDirectory = $userRoot + $name                                                                                                                 ## \\DC01.carpal.local\Home\Ben001
            Set-ADUser $name –HomeDrive $homeDrive –HomeDirectory $homeDirectory                                                                                   
            New-Item –path "$global:FolderVol$homeFolder" -Name $name -type directory -force
        
            $acl = Get-Acl $homeDirectory
            $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
            $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($name,"FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
            $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
            $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
            $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
            Set-Acl $homeDirectory $acl 
        }  
    }
    
    function Set-HomeAllDC
    {
        Get-HomeShareInfo
    }

    if ($fqdn.GetType().BaseType.Name -eq "Array")
    {
        echo "`n"
        Write-Host " !! Replica Domain Controllers detected !!" -ForegroundColor Red
        echo "`n"
        Start-Sleep -s 1
        Write-Host "Configure home folders on all Domain Controllers         [1]"
        Write-Host "Configure home folders only on Primary Domain Controller [2]"

        echo "`n"
        $answer = Read-Host "Please select an option"

        if ($answer -eq 1)
        {
            Set-HomeAllDC
        }
        if ($answer -eq 2)
        {
            Set-HomePDC
        }
        elseif ($answer -ge 2 -or $answer -eq "")
        {
            echo "`n"
            Write-Host "Please provide a value between 1 and 2" -ForegroundColor Red
            Start-Sleep -s 1
        }
    }

    else
    {
       Set-PDCHome 
    }         
}

function Get-HomeShareInfo
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK") 
    {
        $volume = $foldername.SelectedPath  ## A:\
        $global:FolderVol = $volume.Replace(':\','$')
    }

    $global:homeFolder = Read-Host "Enter the name of your home folder"

    $global:shareName = Read-Host "Enter the share name"
}

Set-HomeFolder
```

Comment: `A$` as in ``A:\`` floppy drive?

Comment: No as in C:\ Volume drive. But when I have to create a new folder with a UNC path it only works with the A$ syntax. That's why I formatted the A:\ result to A$ in the Get-HomeShareInfo function. A is just a volume I added in my VM for data storage like home folders etc

Comment: "on a primary domain controller" is this setup from 1999? The whole point of DFS-R is you only need to make the change on one DC

Comment: But in order to setup DFS you need to have the same folder structure on all DCs initially..

Comment: @Can'tC - just create and replicate one folder named HomeDrives or something.  Then every time you add a home drive to a user account it will be replicated.